# How do I change ownership of '/usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so' when it's stopping 'sudo' and 'su' from working properly?

Tags: sudo, root, su

any time I use sudo for any command I get the following errors:

```
sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 0 while loading plugin "sudoers_policy"
sudo: /usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so must be owned by uid 0
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

and each time I try to change owner of sudoers.so I get:

```
chown: changing ownership of '/usr/libexec/sudo/sudoers.so': Operation not permitted
```

I tried to become root using:

```
su root
```

with the right password and I got:

```
su: Authentication failure
```

any operation that requires authentication fails, and I can't uninstall anything.

Comment: what specifically do I have to do in recovery mode to fix this?

Comment: Recovery mode is a root prompt so you can chown the file back to the proper ownership.